# How do I stop Intellij from automatically deleting spaces in .md files?

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

When writing documentation in a README.md file, IntelliJ automatically removes any spaces, which makes it really annoying to type any text. I can add spaces after writing a few words by moving the cursor to the end of the first word/beginning of the next word, and then adding a space, but this is really cumbersome.

My IntelliJ version is this:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)
>
> Build #IU-223.8617.56, built on January 26, 2023

Does someone know what setting I need to change to get rid of this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the various settings under `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Markdown`? There are tabs at the top of that page for "Tabs and Indents", "Spaces", "Blank Lines" and "Wrapping and Braces".

Comment: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Remove trailing spaces on. Did you check this setting?

Comment: These are my current settings that you both mentioned:
`Editor > Code Style > Markdown` | `Spaces`
`Force one space` is checked for each option (between words, after header symbol, after list marker, after blockquote marker)


`Editor > General` | `On Save`
`Remove trailing spaces on: *Modified lines*` 
`Keep trailing spaces on caret line`

but these don't sound like they would change what I want, unless for some reason IntelliJ forces a save after every key pressed? @Rogue @CrazyCoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my IntelliJ and this issue no longer occurred.

Current version is:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition)
>
> Build #IU-231.8109.175, built on March 28, 2023

Looking at the version number it seems they did a rollback?

Answer (score 1):

On IntelliJ, Go in File < Settings < Type "Markdown" in the searchbar < Double-click on Markdown in Code Style < Click on "Spaces" in the tabs of the window.

Now you can manage spaces of Markdown files (.md) :)

I hope it will be the same for you, I'm on IntelliJ 2022.2.1 if you wonder !